# Elegant way to copy substring from char* to std::string

Tags: c++, string

I have this `char*`:

```
char* line = "This is a great day";
string subLine;
```

I want that `subLine` will include: `is a great`

(copy from place 5, the next 10 characters).

Is there a way to do that instead of converting the `char*` to `std::string`?

Comment: Use the iterator constructor.

Comment: RTFM. There are several ways to do this.

Comment: `char const * line` would be better.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the fifth constructor from [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/), as follows:

```
char* line = "This is a great day";
string subLine(&line[5], 10);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [std::string::append](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append).

```
subLine.append(line+5, 10);
```