# JNI: How to substring? How to get caller's package name? Call C code from Java on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I could call a very simple JNI method below from Java on Android somehow. However I have no idea what should I do next.

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_test_ndktest_MyActivity_HelloJNI
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
  {
    (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI");
  }
```

What I want to do are two things...

1. What is compatible Java's substring method.

> ```
> String str1 = new String("Hello World!");
> String new_str1 = str1.substring(2, 5);
> System.out.println(new_str1); // llo
> ```

2. I want to have a limitation to call

I may be able to get caller's package name. I want to avoid calling by unexpecting callers.

I am very grateful if you can share any hints or advices.

Thanks

Comment: What's the concern on #2? That someone will steal your SO and use it in their project?

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev Yes. My concern is hacking my secret keys by someone. I believe that SO is much more secure than JAVA. Do you agree with that? If you know other ways, I am very happy to know that.

Comment: Practically impossible to secure against a determined hacker. Package name checking, for one thing, is not an airtight measure; they can name the package as whatever the NDK library expects and debug like that. Native code is harder to debug than Java, but definitely not impossible. How bad would it be for your business if the keys are stolen?

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev Thanks for your additional comment. Yes, I totally agree with you. I just want to raise the bar against reverse engineering and cracking. Regarding of the package name, I understand what you said, but the using package name is just one option. We will implement mix airtight measures. Someone can have a read access permission for specific data if our keys are stolen. The key has only a few permissions just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do that in Java? As for me the better way is to do this things in java. Sorry if i din't understand something.

As you know you can use C/C++. Did you see this: 
[Elegant way to copy substring from char* to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558730/elegant-way-to-copy-substring-from-char-to-stdstring) or http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry, my question did not explain enough. I'm thinking about obfuscation for saving my secret keys. You know Java is easy to decompile class files.

Comment: @zono As for Java, you can save your keys in KeyStore: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html
Here are some more interesting things about encrypting in android and etc: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#Crypto
Of course you can encrypt your key with some algorythm in NDK and save to sdcard. Just in case you haven't seen it: http://www.dwheeler.com/secure-programs/

Comment: Thank you so much! Saving keys in KeyStore!? That's great. The below link may be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972316/storing-key-using-keystore-in-android 
I will try to implement it.